# Use non-blocking TClientSocket inside a thread

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi, delphi-7

This [Embarcadero](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26693) article describes using a blocking socket inside a thread. If I've created my socket as `ctNonBlocking` and am only writing simple messages to the socket should I be using `TClientWinSocket.SendText`:

```
// Inside TThread::Execute: Option 1
strMessage := 'Hello!';
mySocket.Socket.SendText(strMessage);
```

or should I be creating a `TWinSocketStream` and using `Write`:

```
// Inside TThread::Execute: Option 2
strMessage := 'Hello!';
stream := TWinSocketStream.Create(mySocket.Socket, 1000);
stream.Write(strMessage[1], Length(strMessage));
```

What I am finding is that my application throws an exception when exiting (after `Application.Run()` in the DPR file and impossible to debug) which disappears if I comment out all the TClientSocket code.

Comment: Why are you doing this strange thing?  If you are going to raise a thread, why non-blocking?  Where is your constructor call for the TClientSocket instance?  Please don't say you dumped it onto a form:((

Comment: The socket gets created in an initialisation function of the thread immediately after creating the thread as in `mySocket := TClientSocket.Create(nil);` and then `mySocket.ClientType := ctNonBlocking;`. I set the socket as non-blocking because it seemed easier, but I'm here to learn. If its a strange thing to do, then I shall look at the blocking option...

Comment: See comment to accepted solution. Basically I followed the sample code in the Embarcadero article mentioned in the question (converting the TClientSocket from non-blocking to blocking mode). This has proved to be relatively straightforward. Certainly the way I was using it before was "strange"...using it in blocking mode inside a thread is working great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `TWinSocketStream` if the socket is in non-blocking mode. `TWinSocketStream`'s constructor will raise an exception if the socket is not in blocking mode.  This is stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TWinSocketStream):

> Use TWinSocketStream to read or write information over a **blocking** socket connection...
>
> ...
>
> Note: TWinSocketStream does not work with **non-blocking** sockets.

`TClientSocket` in non-blocking mode works fine in a worker thread (though blocking mode is preferred), provided that the thread has a message loop.  The reason is because in non-blocking mode, `TClientSocket` creates an internal window and associates it with the socket.  This window receives messages from WinSock to trigger `TClientSocket`'s events.  As such, `TClientSocket` in non-blocking mode must be created, used, and destroyed within the same thread context.  Do not access it across thread boundaries.

`TClientSocket` in blocking mode does not have that restriction.

Comment: I'd avoid TClientSocket in non-blocking mode in threads. It uses AllocateHWnd to create its window and that function isn't thread safe. It *does* work most of the time, but then will fail here and there.

Comment: The TClientSocket is only accessed from within the same thread. The only way the "outside world" interacts with the thread is to add messages into a TStringList (wrapped with a critical section for synchronisation) or to get stats from the thread like how many messages have been sent. The thread checks for new messages in TThread::Execute. Thanks for the comments Remy, will look into switching to blocking socket calls.

Comment: @Remy: Quick question relating to `TWinSocketStream`. The documentation (and the Embarcadero sample) show the `TWinSocketStream` being created, used and then freed each time. Is there a problem with creating a `TWinSocketStream` once and re-using it over and over? In the original question, if the socket were changed to blocking, is `TWinSocketStream` preferred to `Socket.SendText(...);`?

Comment: You can create a single instance of `TWinSocketStream` and reuse it for the lifetime of the socket connection. The only real reason to use `TWinSocketStream` is for its timeout handling, but there are other ways to use timeouts without it. The problem with `SendText()` is that it can send partial data, even on a blocking socket, and it returns the number of bytes sent, not the number of characters. It is not ideal. I never use `SendText()` or `ReceiveText()`, always `SendBuf()` and `ReceiveBuf()` instead, or `TWinSocketStream`.

Comment: I've spent this morning converting my code from non-blocking to blocking and it has proved less daunting than I feared! There were problems re-connecting to the server (after I stopped the server listening on the designated port, then started listening again). By setting `mySocket.Active := False;` after sending any messages in the queue, it reconnects each time. Thanks for taking the time, Remy!